# Multiple div boxes in columns

Tags: css, html

Good evening,

I was wondering what the best way to go around getting [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOGb2.png) to be a reality on my website with CSS. The easiest way I can think to do it is using a table but as we all know, tables are evil.

I know about floating left and right and such, but I can only really think of that managing two, maybe three columns and I'd like an indefinite amount. I've also seen ways of positioning absolutely from the left and right edge and such like, but I'd like them to be able to stretch, grow and move depending on the size of the web page.

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: Why wouldn't float: left work?  it shouldn't matter how many columns you have...

Comment: You may need to ask yourself, "Is my data tabular?" If it is then a table is fine. After 3 div based columns, reliability of the layout seems to degrade quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="float: left; padding: 10px; border-style: dotted;">div1</div>
<div style="float: left; padding: 10px; border-style: dotted;">div2</div>
<div style="float: left; padding: 10px; border-style: dotted;">div3</div>
<div style="float: left; padding: 10px; border-style: dotted;">div4</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

EDIT: if you wanna do it with flot right instead you must swap the order of the div's namings div4 div3 div2 div1

Comment: Wow, I had no idea you could do that! Thanks a lot, you've actually saved me many many angry css styling hours from now and the future :)

Comment: If you want even height columns, you'll have to look in a little bit of Javascript magic, but it's pretty simple with the jQuery EqualHeights plugin.